# MS Word - prompt user for custom text ONCE and place it on each label in Mail merge

Tags: ms-word, label, axis-labels, mailmerge

I remember a guy in one of my previous jobs did this thing to ease repeated label printing with some variable data.

He was using MS Word's "Mail merge labels" and his document was set up so that when printing (or opening the file, can't remember), the user was prompted for a value ONCE, e.g. "Enter the work order", and this string was repeated on each label.

When I try to reproduce this, I create a mail merge with labels, and I tried the "ask" and "fillin" from "write and insert fields" and Insert->Quick parts->Field in all ways I could think of, but every time I try to finish and merge, I get a prompt for each label (40 times).

Is there any way to prompt user once and fill the string into all labels without using VBA?

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a FILLIN field with the \o switch. See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-fill-in-field-aa773538-91ee-446a-9a58-1cff8db21d59

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!